# Enable Impersonation for SSRS reports on Azure

Tags: azure, reporting-services, impersonation

In our current Production Setup, we have setup SSRS and have been able to successfully use the SSRS reports in our .NET Web Application since years. We have used Impersonation in Web.Config (there might be other solutions available, we had to go with this) as shown below.

```
<identity  impersonate="true" userName="domainname/username" password="password"></identity>
```

This solution worked well becuase our Active Di
rectory and SSRS server are located in the same Network / domain.

Now, as part of our Azure migration, we have migrated our SSRS server to an Azure VM. and we are able to view the reports using Report Server Manager within the VM. Now, when we access the Web Application (App Service - Web App), we are getting the following error. Below is the updated impersonation attribute that we have used.

```
<identity  impersonate="true" userName="username@ouremailaddressdomainname.onmicrosoft.com" password="password"></identity>
```

"Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The user name or password is incorrect"

Obviously, this is because of the fact that we don't have a Active Directory domain setup in Azure. Below are my questions.

1. Can we utilize the users available in the default Directory that gets created on Azure?
2. If yes, how do I specify the impersonization?

Thanks,
Prawin

Comment: if this question is still valid, where does your web application resides after you migrated the SSRS to Azure VM?

Comment: My web application would be in an App Service

Answer (score 0):

With your planned setup you cannot use identity impersonation. This is because the AppService Web Apps do run in an isolated sand-boxed environment which cannot be part of a Windows Domain.

You have couple of options:

- Change the reporting server to use mixed mode Authentication and create local for the SQL Server login and user with appropriate permissions. Then configure your reporting application to provide these SQL Server credentials
- Move your Web Application to same VM (will not require Domain environment) as your Reporting Server (or just the part which deals with the reports)
- Move your application to a separate VM and utilize the Azure Active Directory Domain Services to make the VMs part of same domain (an overkill IMO)

I would vote for the first option, as it requires least changes and leverages PaaS services (App Service). Everything else is overkill or just an abuse of the cloud platform.